# How to customize route config if user already logged in asp mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Hi I am trying to make logged in user to his/her dashboard

I know how to do in Home Controller to redirect to user to specific controller, but then logged-in user never can go to Home/Index.

Below is my plan in RouteConfig.cs:

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        if(user is logged in already)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LoggedIn",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Manage", action = "Dashboard", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Please help!

**Update!**

Sorry about unclear. After user log in, I made them to go Manage/Dashboard.

So this is the situation: If one user logged in and used my web, and closed the web browser (without log-off), then when the user open web browser and come to my web he will be automatically redirect to the Manage/Dashboard.

Right now, when the user closed the web browser and open my web from the beginning, he always see Home/Index.

I want logged-in users who closed web browser and come back to my web (still logged in) automatically go to their dashboard by do something in routes..

**Update:**
I solved it.
If Home/Index action can check or get current user id, then redirect him to dashboard.

However, I didn't apply this logic. Because business logic was not right.

Comment: are you tying set two default routes?

Comment: what happens when users goes to Home/index after login?

Comment: I think one default route will be fine. So when user was logged in the default route should be going to Dashboard.

Comment: @Usman Home/index is a just welcome page.

Comment: i cant understand the problem! are you getting error when going to Home/index after login?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit it to explain better what the *expected behavior* is. Route values cannot (or rather, should not) be changed after the application starts. But for your use case, the default route seems to cover it anyway. Perhaps you just need to redirect the user to the dashboard when they login, but allow them to go back to the home page? Please explain the use case in detail - we can't read your mind.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Sorry about unclear. After user log in, I made them to go Manage/Dashboard. So this is the situation: If one user logged in and used my web, and closed the web browser (without log-off), then when the user open web browser and come to my web he will be automatically redirect to the Manage/Dashboard.

Right now, when the user closed the web browser and open my web from the beginning, he always see Home/Index.

I want logged-in users who closed web browser and come back to my web (still logged in) automatically go to their dashboard by do something in routes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public ActionResult Index()
{
  If(user is logged in already)
  {
     Return RedirectToAction("dashboard","manage");
   }
// code something
}
```

Write RedirecttoAction method in Home controller index action for navigate to other webpage.

Comment: No this is not what i wanted. I want when user opens my web then go to his dashboard. But he also can go to Home/Index later. Your answer is forcing user to go his dashboard always, never can go to Home/Index.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to the home action.

```
Public ActionResult Index(string show)
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && String.IsNullOrEmpty(show))
    {
        Return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Manage");
    }
    else
    {
        Return View();
    }
}
```

And for the home page url on their dashboard have a link going to /Home/Index?show=true